# recursively convex plane curves

Tags: convex-geometry, plane-geometry

For the lack of a better term let's call a convex simple loop $u(t)$ recursively convex if for any $n \geq 0$ the $n$-th derivative $u^{(n)}(t)$ is a convex simple loop. We conjecture that any recursively convex loop is an ellipse.

Here is a more formal setup. Let $u(t): [0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be a closed infinitely smooth curve. We will identify $\mathbb R^2$ with $\mathbb C$ whenever convenient.

We exdend $u(t)$ to $\mathbb R$ by periodicity. We require that $u(0) = 1$, and that it is symmetric around $0$, i.e. $u(t+\pi) = -u(t)$. Let $u^{(n)}(t) \equiv \frac{d^n}{dt^n} u(t)$ denote the $n$-th derivative of $u(t)$. Let $u^{(n)}(t) = r_n(t) e^{i \phi_n(t)}$ be the respective polar decomposinions. We observe that if $\det(u^{(n)}(t), u^{(n+1)}(t)) > 0$ then $\phi_n(t)$ is strictly monotonically increasing (and the inverse is almost true).

Is the following proposition true?

If for all $n\geq 0$ the function
\begin{equation}
\label{prop-cond}
\det(u^{(n)}(t), u^{(n+1)}(t)) > 0
\end{equation}
then $u(t)$ is an ellipse.

Motivation and Discussion.

1. If $\phi_0(t)$ is monotonic then $u(t)$ is a simple loop. If, on top of this, $\phi_1(t)$ is monotonic too, i.e. the angle between the tangent line at $u(t)$ and $\mathbb R^+$ is increasing then $u(t)$ is convex. It seems like every additional requirement of $\phi_n(t)$ being monotonic adds a great deal of regularity to $u(t)$.
2. The unit circle $u(t) = e^{it}$ fits the bill. This follows from observing that a) $\det(u, v) = \Im (\bar{u} v)$ for $u, v \in \mathbb C$ (here $\Im$ denotes the imaginary part, and $\bar{u}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $u$), and b) $u^{(n+1)}(t) = i \cdot u^{(n)}(t)$.
3. If $u(t)$ fits the bill then so does $A u(t)$ for any $2*2$ matrix $A$ s.t. $\det(A)>0$. Since $A$ of the unit circle is an ellipse any ellipse satisfies (\ref{prop-cond})
4. One line of attack is to somehow define an inverse of $\frac{d}{dt}$, let's denote it $T$, and show that for any simple loop $C$ the image $T^n C$ converges to the unit circle.